# IIS Application Pool Optimisation

Tags: iis, application-pool

We are experiencing some performance issues with one of our websites and one of the things I am looking at is optimising the application pool. Are there any recommended methods of calculating maximum virtual/used memory to allow the pool?

Answer (score 0):

The default settings of IIS are pretty well thought out.  I'd first start by placing the application in its own application pool to make sure there aren't any other websites that might be causing the problem.

From there, I'd work at analyzing the code to make sure it is the resources the application has access to that are limiting the website.  If the resources are what is limiting, it should be easy to figure out what needs priority in the application pool.

If your application is running massive memory software, it would be apparent by the spike and eventual ceiling hit of no more memory available, thus, you'd up your memory for that pool.  Likewise, if the site just bogs down over time, you might check how long your sessions are staying alive and possibly shorten them.  Just some things to start out with.

As far as hard and fast rules, I haven't come across any and usually it is so 'per-application' specific, that it is hard to define.  I would just pay attention to performance counters and then turn one thing on, check them again, and then try another thing, making sure to keep all tests agnostic so you know what is working and what is not.